# Windows Web Farm Framework Memory Allocation Issue

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, iis

We have a web farm running two servers (W2K8 R2). Let's name them web01 and web02. Web01 has no problem, but web02 has a strange memory allocation problem with the WebFarmAgentService. For unknown reason this service allocated 10 times more RAM than similar service at web01.

Has anyone seen this problem or have any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: This is a similar thread I opened on the IIS forums a while back, however I don't really like the last comment there as a solution: http://forums.iis.net/p/1188619/2019293.aspx